# How to enable oci in xampp 5.6.3?

Tags: php, dll, xampp, oci8

I am facing some issue while starting Apache server via XAMPP. I have installed XAMPP Version 5.6.3.

When I start the Apache server from xampp control panel, an error message is displayed as shown below:

[image: Figure-1]

On clicking 'OK' button, another dialog box is displayed as shown:

[image: Figure-2]

The thing is I wanted to use OCI instead of mysql. so I have commented out the mysql extensions and uncommented the OCI extension in **php.ini** file.

[image: Figure-3]

The *php_oci8_12c.dll* file is the only file available in the extensions (ext) folder of php in xampp. Hence I included the line in the php.ini as shown in the above image.

Since then I am getting this error.

I have installed instant client 12.1 as well but no luck. I also tried copying the OCI.dll from instantclient_12_1 and pasting it in c:/xampp/php and c:/xampp/apache/bin. The error still persists.

Need help..

**UPDATE:** I removed other oracle paths in PATH of environment variables, keeping only the instantclient path. Now I am getting this error..

[image: Figure-4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue. The problem was that I was trying to use a 64 bit DLL(php_oci8_12g.dll) in a 32 bit PHP. I downloaded a 32 bit instantClient and it works now! :-)

instantclient-basic-nt-12.1.0.2.0.zip

Comment: I am facing same issue, can you help me as configured you suggested

Answer (score 3):

Well, I've installed XAMPP 1.8.2, PHP 5.4 and Apache 2.0, and I use php_oci8_11g.dll and works fine.

You are trying use php_oci8_12g.dll, I recommend you read this link http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/technote-php-instant-12c-2088811.html with especifications for run oci12g.

Comment: Hi @Pablo, I have read the document regarding the oci8 and instantclient 12c in the link you provided and made some changes but now I am getting another error. I have mentioned it as an **UPDATE** in my question

Comment: Your windows is 64 or 32 bits? Because I guess the documentation is inconsistent. It says you must install Apache x64, InstantClient x64, ocidll x64 but php 5.5 x32. Try run it on Windows 64 bits and with all software (php, apache, xampp, instantclient, ocidll) also 64 bits

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue after stuck 2-3 days .

Before follow steps Some things to remmember .
1- I am using win 8.1 64 bit .
2- Using Xampp 5.6.31 32 bit .
3- Using instaclient 12.2.0.1 64 bit (Because my win 8.1 is 64 Bit ) .

Now steps  are below -

Step 1 - Download xampp 5.6.31 32 bit and install it .

Step 2 - Download and install oracle 11g R2

Step 3 - Download and install OTN (oracle instaclient 12.2.0.1 )

- Extract all files in any drive in my case i have extract in **C:\oracle\instaclient12.2.0.1**
- Add (**C:\oracle\instaclient12.2.0.1**  ) it to the path variables of the system. and also add new variable under variable of system with name TNS_ADMIN and put same path (**C:\oracle\instaclient12.2.0.1** ) in its value .
- Its time to set PHP.INI here uncomment following (see image below)
  [PHP.ini setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpD4A.png)
- Copy 3 files from **C:\oracle\instaclient12.2.0.1**  oci.dll,oraociei12.dll and oraons.dll to xampp apache\bin . by this step Unable to load dynamic library issue has been resolved .
  [Unable to load dynamic library issue solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sambu.png)
- Now restart Apache on xampp and check info.php on browser . OCI8 module will appear there enable .

Enjoy !!!.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem related to OCI8 and XAMPP for days in a row, the problem was shown as:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect()

I was able to correct it using the php that comes by default with XAMPP. I'm using windows 10 64 bits as well, but used xampp-win32-7.3.2-0-VC15 (php 7.3.2). To summarize, I was able to get a correct configuration by doing everything with 32 bits versions (except the o.s). The full story and how I've done it:

If you go to your xampp/php directory through cmd, in my case it was "C:\xampp\php", and start the php by the simple command "php" it will probably show what dlls **are not being found in the etc folder or which of those are not Win 32 compatible**. If you get this problem, you will not be able to see the OCI8 page when opening a phpinfo() page:

[image]

If that's the case, with win 32 compatibility problems or not finding the dlls that you are certain are there, you should unistall XAMPP and reinstall it using a x32 version. The phpinfo page will show x86 Architecture. Remember to remove in the path variables any source that miss locate your php in use, the point here is to use the one given by default in XAMPP. If you need by any reason to use another php installation, remember to use x86 architecture.
If you need an updated OCI8 dll you can download it on https://pecl.php.net/package/oci8 , but remember to check the Thread Safety compatibility, you can find it on your phpinfo page as well. In my case it was enough to use the one provided by XAMPP.

After this, you have to enable the extension:

```
 extension=oci8_12c
```

in the php.ini configuration file. It was enough for me to enable only this one, although some people suggests to also enable extension=pdo_oci. My suggestion is to try this only if you failed to install with the path here shown. It's also good to check if you are set in the correct path regarding the extensions, in my case:

```
extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext"
```

After this, you have to download the Oracle Instant Client. Since you are using x86 architecture (you must use this one), you need to find a 32-bit version of the OIC, but is also important to check which one is compatible with the extension you uncommented. In my case, of oci8_12c, it was instantclient-basic-nt-12.2.
The final step is to unzip it to a folder, like "C:\instantclient_12_2" and add it to the path variables of the system. 
Reload apache and check if the OCI8 is shown correcly.