# Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in C:\xampp81\htdocs\aaainc\db.php on line 71

Tags: php, oracle, oci8

i have a problem with function oci_connect. now, i used xampp version 5.6.14-4, i've tried to uncomment this code like the suggestions in other posts on stack overflow

```
extension=php_oci8.dll      ; Use with Oracle 10gR2 Instant Client
extension=php_oci8_11g.dll  ; Use with Oracle 11gR2 Instant Client
```

i already restart the xampp, but still have the same error..

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in    
C:\xampp81\htdocs\aaa\inc\db.php on line 71
```

is there any step that i missed? can you help me?

thank you so much :D

Comment: Chech in your php_info that the extension is enabled

Comment: then what else? i don't understand with phpinfo()

Comment: i search in phpinfo(), there is no oci8 support in xampp 5.6.14-4 . then, what should i do ? previously, i used xampp 1.6.4, but now i update this xampp into 5.6.14

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29009665/how-to-enable-oci-in-xampp-5-6-3

Comment: still did'nt help :(

Comment: Only one of those extensions should be enabled, not both. Is an Oracle client installed on the same machine as XAMPP? Have you read the [requirements](http://php.net/manual/en/oci8.requirements.php) and followed the [installation](http://php.net/manual/en/oci8.installation.php) instructions?

Comment: Definitely. because, previously i use xampp version 1.6.4 and its work. and now i update the xampp into the latest version xampp 5.6.14, but cannot connect into oracle database. is there any different oracle instant client require between xampp 1.6.4 and 5.6.14 ? which makes it unable to connect to oracle database ?

Comment: when i check in php.ini file, there is extension=php_oci8.dll; and extension=php_oci8_11g.dll; but in the extension directory extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext", this dll is saved as php_oci8_12c.dll . is this a mistake from xampp(apachefriends.org)?

Comment: That would seem to be the problem, yes. disable the original two extensions (by adding a semi-colon `;` at the start of the line), and create a new line as `extension=php_oci8_12c.dll`.

Comment: when i add extension=php_oci8_12c.dll to php.ini, there is an error, the error said "The procedure entry point php_checkuid could not be located in the dynamic link library php5ts.dll." . i dont know how to fix this, so confusing..

Answer (score 0):

you can also see this answer from this question

here is tutorial of installing oci8 drivers for PHP

[my answer for same question please review this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34494636/2125924)