# Cant connect PHP(XAMPP) to Oracle using OCI8

Tags: php, oracle, oci8, instantclient

Thanks for all the help in advance. I cannot connect my PHP to ORACLE using OCI8. The specs of softwares that i use are

- Windows 10 Version:  Home  64-bit
- XAMPP Version: 5.6.24
- PHP Version - 5.6.24
- PHP Script framework - ZEnd Framework
- ORACLE - XE 11g - OracleXE112_Win64.zip
- Instant client - 11.2 - instantclient-basic-nt-11.2.0.2.0.zip
- ORACLE_HOME variable = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server
- PATH - has this this value ORACLE_HOME\bin

I am using NAVICAT as my mysql client and able to connect to the database using this. Setting like instant client path and sqlplus had to set in this and all working fine.

Now the real issue is connecting PHP to ORACLE using OCI8.
I have used this link to download the correct OCI version for the php version i have. **https://pecl.php.net/package/oci8**. I followed the instruction  **Use 'pecl install oci8-2.0.12' to install
for PHP 5.2 - PHP 5.6** from this link and downloaded all the libs under this and they are

- 5.6 Non Thread Safe (NTS) x86
- 5.6 Thread Safe (TS) x86
- 5.6 Non Thread Safe (NTS) x64
- 5.6 Thread Safe (TS) x64

Tried installing all the **php_oci8_11g.dll** files from the above libs in the **ext** folder of XAMPP one by one. Reset the apache and then tried running the script,but no luck. this was the error message i get

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception' with
>   message 'The oci driver is not currently installed' in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\b2bapptest\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php:112
>   Stack trace: #0
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\b2bapptest\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(448):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect() #1
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\b2bapptest\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('select * from a...', Array) #2
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\b2bapptest\application\models\MiscMapper.php(790):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('select * from a...') #3
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\b2bapptest\application\layouts\scripts\layout.phtml(53):
>   Application_Model_MiscMapper->getActiveAnnouncements() #4
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\b2bapptest\library\Zend\View.php(108):
>   include('D:\xampp\htdocs...') #5
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\b2bapptest\library\Zend\View\Abstract.php(880):
>   Zend_View->_run('D:\xampp\htdocs...') #6
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\b2bapptest\library\Zend\Layout.php(796):
>   Zend_View_Abstract->render('layout.phtml') #7 D:\xampp\htdocs\b2 in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\b2bapptest\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php on
>   line 112

What am i missing, could someone plz help, i have been with this for over a week to find a solution :(

Comment: Just an update to the above question - after uploading the new php_oci8_11g.dll file to ext folder, i have added a new extension=php_oci8_11g.dll in the php.ini file and reset the apache to run the script again.

Comment: one more update..this is what i get after running php in cmd D:\xampp\php>php
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'D:\xampp\php\ext\php_oci8_11g.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem related to OCI8 and XAMPP for days in a row, the problem was shown as:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect()

I was able to correct it using the php that comes by default with XAMPP. I'm using windows 10 64 bits as well, but used xampp-win32-7.3.2-0-VC15 (php 7.3.2). To summarize, I was able to get a correct configuration by doing everything with 32 bits versions (except the o.s).

I've seen many problems regarding OCI8 being solved just by turning everything to 32-bits, I think it worths a try. In this question [How to enable oci in xampp 5.6.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29009665/how-to-enable-oci-in-xampp-5-6-3/57613643#57613643) I've answered the complete path I've done

Comment: Also see https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/installing-xampp-for-php-and-oracle-database