# yii2-advanced with oracle database connection issues

Tags: php, oracle, pdo, database-connection, yii2-advanced-app

I'm trying to connect yii2-advanced project with oracle database, here is the 'db' component code inside  `common\main-local.php`.

```
'db' => [
        'class' => 'CDbConnection',
        'dsn' => 'oci:dbname=127.0.0.1:1521/xyz;charset=UTF8',
        'username' => 'xyz',
        'password' => 'xyz', 
    ],
```

Now, if I use `'class' => "CDbConnection"` as a class, it shows following exception,

```
Not instantiable – yii\di\NotInstantiableException

Failed to instantiate component or class "CDbConnection".

↵ Caused by: ReflectionException

Class CDbConnection does not exist

in C:\xampp\htdocs\ramisha\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php at line 507
```

I have no idea why is it missing in my project. Also, if I use `'class' => 'yii\db\Connection'`, inside `db` component it shows following error:

```
Database Exception – yii\db\Exception

SQLSTATE[HY000]: pdo_oci_handle_factory: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener

(ext\pdo_oci\oci_driver.c:714)
↵

Caused by: PDOException

SQLSTATE[HY000]: pdo_oci_handle_factory: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener

(ext\pdo_oci\oci_driver.c:714)

in C:\xampp\htdocs\ramisha\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Connection.php at line 712
```

Which one is the correct class to be used for connecting oracle database to yii2 project with PDO?

- I have checked for listener.ora file, which is missing in the oracle folder's sub-directories, is it a necessary file?
- I have followed [this guide](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/installing-xampp-for-php-and-oracle-database) to
  set instantclient_19_10 in oracle folder and set it as path variable in system environment.
- Followed one of the answers from this [How to enable oci in xampp 5.6.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29009665/how-to-enable-oci-in-xampp-5-6-3) to set PHP.INI and xampp configuration for oci driver
- "php -m" shows following the list
  [PHP Modules]

```
 - bcmath
 - calendar
 - Core
 - ctype
 - curl
 - date
 - dom
 - exif
 - filter
 - gd
 - gettext
 - hash
 - iconv
 - imap
 - json
 - libxml
 - mbstring
 - mysqli
 - mysqlnd
 - openssl
 - pcre
 - PDO
 - pdo_mysql
 - pdo_sqlite
 - pdo_sqlsrv
 - Phar
 - readline
 - Reflection
 - session
 - SimpleXML
 - soap
 - SPL
 - sqlsrv
 - standard
 - tidy
 - tokenizer
 - wddx
 - xml
 - xmlreader
 - xmlrpc
 - xmlwriter
 - zip
 - zlib
```

- `phpinfo()` shows the following:
  [image: phpinfo output]
- `print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers());` shows following:
  [image: getAvailableDrivers output]

Where exactly is the issue and what to do?